# How to change publisher name in Google Play

Tags: android, publisher

I just recently posted my first app to Google Play. When I search for my app, I would see my app name, and underneath the app name it says who published it. In my case, my app says it is published under my full legal name. I would like to change it so that my app says it is published by my company name. How can I go about changing this? I don't mind removing my app from Google Play and uploading a new app if I have to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Comment: @Black siriusly?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In the Developer Console, go to Settings, and change the 'Developer Name'.

Note that this name is the same for *all* of your apps. If you want to keep your name for other apps, you need a separate developer account and file for an app transfer.

Comment: Thank you. I successfully made the change.

Comment: Could you explain how to get to developer name? cant find it

Comment: Nota : I had to wait for a few minutes until the cache was updated.

Comment: Will this operation reset our existing app's Download count ?

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda No, it will not change app's download count

Comment: from play console: "The developer name is displayed to users under your application name. Changes to the developer name will be reviewed by Google and can take up to 7 days."

Comment: Is it possible to replace the developer name for specific app?

Comment: Create a new app

Comment: I would like to add that it could drop your search rankings on play store

Comment: @JaydeepW after changing developer name in console  for already published app. it will reflect in playstore without any update of the app?

Comment: @Kousalya It should. As the developer name is not tied to an application.

Comment: For now there is a setup menu, but there is no settings menu.. And there is no developer name there...

Comment: is it any limitations to change the dev name ?

Answer (score 13):

Google often changes its design. So for now we need to go to [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/about/) main page, then select in the left pane "Developer Page".
There, we can change the developer name.
[image]

Comment: I like this answer because it's correct for the current interface; however, It's not required (anymore) to upload profile images. Just changed my name and it's now under review. I suggest you remove the bit about profile images, and add that after changing your name, it will be reviewed by Google before being updated in the store

Comment: This answer still work, if you just need to update only Developer name don't mind other sections.

Answer (score 7):

Sign In to Developer Console
Click the Gear Icon on the Left hand Panel
Under Settings > Developer Name > Change it to your Desired Name.
Ctrl + F5 > to see the changes..