# How to change text of link under title for google play store app

Tags: google-play-console

I need to change text of link under title marked on image bellow. In google developer console I found how to change pretty much everything else, but cannot found how to change this.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change publisher name in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172814/how-to-change-publisher-name-in-google-play)